# Does an Android factory data reset delete or reset the "Android" folder on a SD card?

Tags: android, reset

I am implementing a backup manager in my Android app. For backups on the SD card, I plan to use an app-specific subfolder of the automatically created (since API level 19) "Android" folder on the SD card. My app has a min API of 19. My question is: Does an Android factory data reset also delete or reset the "Android" folder on a SD card? Is the answer always the same for all Android versions and all device manufacturers?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Doing a factory reset WILL NOT modify the sdcard in any way. 


https://android.stackexchange.com/a/18038/164169

Comment: Your question is related with operating system mechanism not programming. It would be better to ask [here](https://android.stackexchange.com).